# Change ouput for loop in bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I've these data :

```
2020-01-01-00-00
2020-01-01-06-00
2020-01-01-12-00
2020-01-01-18-00
```

I would like to display these data like this :

```
[ 2020-01-01-00-00, 2020-01-01-06-00, 2020-01-01-12-00, 2020-01-01-18-00 ]
```

I try this :

```
for i in $(cat Test2.txt)
do
tr -d "\n" <<< $i," "
done
```

The output is :

```
2020-01-01-00-00, 2020-01-01-06-00, 2020-01-01-12-00, 2020-01-01-18-00,
```

Then I try :

```
for i in $(cat Test2.txt)
do
echo " [ `tr -d "\n" <<< "'$i'"," "` ]"
done
```

But the output is :

```
[ '2020-01-01-00-00',  ]
[ '2020-01-01-06-00',  ]
[ '2020-01-01-12-00',  ]
[ '2020-01-01-18-00',  ]
```

Could you show me how to do that ?

Comment: What is this data? How do you get this? and who is the receiver for this formatted data? knowing these information would help us provide better and more meaningful solutions

Answer (score 2):

[Don't read lines with `for`.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

A common arrangement is to use a separator prefix which changes after the first iteration.

```sh
prefix='['
while read -r line; do
    printf '%s %s' "$prefix" "$line"
    prefix=','
done <Test2.txt
printf ' ]\n'
```

I'll second the suggestion to use a JSON-specific tool if your task is to generate valid JSON, though. This is pesky and somewhat brittle.

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output looks like JSON, if so you can use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) for this. E.g:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs]' Test2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf`

```
data="
    2020-01-01-00-00
    2020-01-01-06-00
    2020-01-01-12-00
    2020-01-01-18-00
"

printf -v data %s,\  $data
printf "[ ${data%, } ]"
```

Answer (score 0):

a
 tricky bit of perl:

```sh
perl -00 -pe 'chomp; s/\n/, /g; BEGIN {print "[ "} END {print " ]\n"}' Test2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html),

```
$: sed -n '$!H; ${H; x; s/\n/, /g; s/$/ ]\n/; s/^,/[/; p;}' infile
```

In [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html),

```
$: dat="$(printf "%s, " $(<infile))";  printf "[ ${dat%, } ]\n";
```

in ['awk'](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html),

```
$: awk 'BEGIN{ printf "[ "; sep=""; } { printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep=", "; } END{ print " ]"; }' infile
```